# Using regular expressions to extract "identifiers" from another c++ file

Tags: c++, regex

I have to write a program that extracts identifiers from another C++ file. Generally, I have a problem with writing a regular expression which would extract these "identifiers" that are basically strings starting with any letter (case insensitive) or an underscore. Here is the sample code:

```
std::string line1 = "#include <iostream>";
std::string line2 = "int main() {";
std::string line3 = "   std::cout << \"Hello World!\";\n";
std::string line4 = "}";
```

I would like the regular rexpression to extract from this code following substrings:
**include, iostream, int, main, std, cout**

I've created a regex object so far and a variable **matches** to store matched substrings:

```
std::smatch matches;
std::regex pattern("[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+");
```

Generally, I do know how to build whole program OOP-based, just got stayed with this regular expression.

Here is my function that takes **line** argument from another class method which reads a file line by line.

```
void IdentifierCounter::extract_identifiers(std::string line) {
std::regex reg("[\w]+");
if (regex_match(line, reg)) {
    std::cout << "Found a match!" << "\n";
}
```

}

The whole code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
class IdentifierCounter {
public:
   std::string file_name;
   std::vector<std::string> vec_of_identifiers;
   std::map<std::string, int> identifiers;
   IdentifierCounter(std::string file_name);
   void extract_identifiers(std::string line);
};

IdentifierCounter::IdentifierCounter(std::string file_name) {
   std::ifstream file;
   std::string line;
   file.open(file_name);
   while (file) {
     getline(file, line);
     vec_of_identifiers.push_back(line);
}
file.close();
for (auto line : vec_of_identifiers) {
    extract_identifiers(line);
}
}

void IdentifierCounter::extract_identifiers(std::string line) {
std::regex reg("[\w]+");
if (regex_match(line, reg)) {
    std::cout << "Found a match!" << "\n";
}
}


int main()
{
IdentifierCounter obj1("Lab 11.cpp");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Does the regex work?  (Note that you are matching spaces as well).

Comment: You really can't use a regex to parse C++.  The language is too complex for that.  For instance, `int (bar) = 42`; is legal, and declares a variable named `bar` of type `int`, but it's really hard to get a regex for that.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The goal is to modify the pattern to make it able to extract substrings like I said above. I want to catch everything that starts with any letter or an underscore.

Comment: Then please show the input and output that failed. Also show exactly how you are using the regex to extract matches.

Comment: The "line" variables are an example to show you guys what the output I expect, I generally store these lines in a vector of strings.

Comment: *Show* the code you are using, don't just describe it. Note also the comment that points out that you are going to have a terrible time trying to parse c++ source with regexes.

Comment: Edited and pasted the whole code.

Comment: You don't appear to be looking at the matches found at all. How do you know if it's working or not?

Comment: I've created sample variable which stores "#include <iostream>" and I am not getting matched substrings with my regular expression. But when I change this sample string to "include iostream" it finds only one substring, which is the whole string, but I would like to expect 2 substrings: "include" and "iostream" separately. The pattern was:
std::regex pattern("([a-zA-Z_ ]*)");

Comment: `std::regex reg("[\w]+");` won't compile, do you mean you want `std::regex reg("\\w+");`?

Comment: What about comments?  Do you allow the content of comments to be searched?

Comment: No, only basic statements like if's, types, keywords etc. Just everything which starts from a letter or an underscore, it can be followed by digits, but has to be one word.

Comment: If you want to parse C++ you need a proper compiler. Regex won't do. I'd recommend looking into Clangs [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html)

Comment: But I'm storing the lines of code in strings, so I am not really able to extract these "words" in regex?